# Beam display from any computer to shared display

Tags: networking, video

There are probably a lot of ways to skin this cat. Looking for the cleanest.

In our office, we have a large display in a common area. We want to allow any computer in our office (mac, linux, windows) to output its video on the large display.

Since some of the computers in the office are stationary, and it's not practical to run video cables everywhere, it would be preferable to make this all happen through the network.

It is also possible for us to connect a dedicated (& networked) PC to the large display.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to hook a PC to the display, VNC may be an option. A Google search will bring up many flavours for the PC (UltraVNC (my fave), Tight.., Real..) etc., it's built into the Mac already and your version of Linux almost certainly has a repository copy if it's not installed by default.

You would start a VNC server on all the outlying PCs and use VNC viewer on the PC connected to the display to select your target machine.

Comment: +1 for vnc. VNC can be considered a security risk, so be sure to password the service on each host machine and, for good measure, consider not running the service automatically at boot. Also, mismatched resolution settings between host and client might not make for your optimal solution. many flavors of VNC (e.g. RealVNC) are free-ish

Comment: VNC is an option, but I'm not sure how the "Server" could initiate the connection the the Client. eg: I'm sitting at my desk and want to share my screen ...